# Probability that the number is odd

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a task:

The random vector $(X,Y)$ has a continuous density distribution with density:

$f(x,y)=2$ for $\{(X,Y):(X,Y) \in(0,1)^2,y>x)\}$

Calculate the probability, that $[\frac{Y}{X}]$ is an odd number. By $[z]$ we understand the closest integer to $z$ number.

So in my opinion the solution is
$\int\limits_{0}^{2/3} \int\limits_{x}^{x \cdot 3/2} 2 dydx + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int\limits_{0}^{\frac{1}{2n+3/2}} \int\limits_{(2n+1/2)x}^{(2n+3/2)x} 2 dydx= \frac{2}{9}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{2}{4n+3})^2 $ and it is equal approximately $0.41$ but I have the answer and the answer is $0.57$.
Where did I mistake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your integration bounds are off. In an integral, you shouldn't have the integral's bounds depend on the variable you're integrating with respect to.

Comment: Thanks, You mean that $dy$ should be first than $dx$. I corrected.

Comment: Your upper bounds are too strict. I recommend trying to explicitly write inequalities such that $x, y$ are in the domain and $\left[\frac{y}{x}\right]=k$ for odd $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=[y/x]$. $k=1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}x < y < \frac{3}{2}x$. Using $x<y<1$, one can write $x < y < \min(\frac{3}{2}x,1)$. Then first term is $$\int_0^1 \int_x^{\min(\frac{3}{2}x,1)} f(x,y) dy dx=\int_0^{2/3} \int_x^{\frac{3}{2}x} f(x,y) dy dx+\int_{2/3}^{1} \int_x^{1} f(x,y) dy dx=\frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$$
The same error for other terms:
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2n+3/2}}\int_{(2n+1/2)x}^{(2n+3/2)x} 2dydx+\int_{\frac{1}{2n+3/2}}^{\frac{1}{2n+1/2}}\int_{(2n+1/2)x}^{1} 2dydx=\frac{4}{(4n+1)(4n+3)}$$
$$\frac{1}{3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{(4n+1)(4n+3)}=\frac{\pi}{2}-1$$